# Images slowing down application

Tags: android-studio, optimization, android-recyclerview, image-scaling

In my application i have sqlite database which stores paths to images which are later displayed as items in recyclerview in different tabs in tablayout. For example in tab vegetables there are images of vegetables ect. This images slow down application strongly, tabs are loading 5-10 seconds sometimes crashing. I've tried changing images to nodpi, it helped a little bit but not much. If I'm using vector images it works perfectly. What can i do ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem in my case was using unformated images via function `image.background =`  I've changed it to `image.setImageUri` and let android studio do mipmaps of my images.